# TypeScript: Specifying a variable is a descendent of abstract class

Tags: typescript

Suppose

```
abstract class A {
  protected abstract f(): void;
}

class B extends A {
  public f() { return 'B'; }
}

class C extends A {
  public f() { return 'C'; }
}
```

and I want a array containing `B` and `C`. It can be done by:

```
let arr: Array<B | C> = [/* lots of objects */];
arr.forEach(item => item.f());
```

Here, I want to make `Array<B | C>` more flexible and general so that it would be `Array</*descendent of A*/>`.

Could someone give me an advice?

Comment: Why not `let arr: Array<A>`, `A` is abstract, no instances of `A` can be created, so all instances in the array will be subtypes of `A`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir The problem in case of doing that is: `item.f()` throws compilation error, *Propperty f is protected and only accessible within class A and its subclasses*

Comment: well if `f` is meant to be public on all derived classes, why is it declared `protected` in `A` ? make it public and all will work as expected

Comment: could you not just use an interface instead of your abstract `interface MyInterface { f: () => void; }` and implement that on any extended class then you could use `let arr: MyInterface[]`?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Uhm because `Base` is an abstract class. I am not sure whether a workaround --- defining an empty `public f()` in abstract class and overiding it in subclasses.

Comment: @DavidBarker Thanks for a comment. If there is absolutely no way to do what I want with *class*, I'll consider using interface. Then I need to other consequences.

Comment: Oh you mean `public abstract`...

Comment: @Jeon I'm not saying that there isn't another way, just the way I saw this it seemed an interface was more sensible, however you may have private functionality in your abstract that will obviously not work with an interface. Titian Cernicova-Dragomir has a sensible solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `A` as the array item. `f` should be public if you plan on invoking it on derived types from outside the class, there is no restriction on abstract members to be protected:

```
abstract class A {
    public abstract f(): string;
}

class B extends A {
    public f() { return 'B'; }
}

class C extends A {
    public f() { return 'C'; }
}

let arr: Array<A> = [/* lots of objects */];
arr.forEach(item => item.f());
```

Comment: Declaring a return type of `void` on the abstract but `string` on the descendant classes doesn't feel quite right. It would appear, as it is to violate Liskovs SP.

Comment: @DavidBarker I just copy pasted, you are of course right